# anchor tags don't work on elements with z-index -1 and positioned elements overlap sticky menus

Tags: html, css

I am developing a responsive auction site with sticky menu on top and fixed menu on bottom.

I have a series of boxes (div's) in the body so content flows with viewport size. Within each box/div I have a picture at the top and a text block at a fixed location at the bottom of the box. The text block includes anchor tags to description pages.

To do this I have to use position: relative for the box/div and position: absolute for the text block. However, now the boxes/div's scroll over top of the fixed menus because of position css properties. If I put z-index of -1 on the div's, they scroll below the menus they way I want them to but then the text links in the text blocks are not clickable because they are part of the back-most element. I need to be able to click them. Any ideas please on how to get my div's underlapping the sticky menus but still letting me click the text links.

CSS:

```
.salebox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
border: 2px solid #000000;
width: 150px;
height: 220px;
margin: auto 10px 20px 10px;
z-index: -1;
}

.sale_photo {
width: 150px;
max-height: 138px;
}

.salebox_text {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 145px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="salebox">
    <img src="pic1..." class="sale_photo">
    <div class="salebox_text">
        <strong>Charity Auction</strong>
        <br>Ends 2016-06-14
        <br><a href="charity_sale_page.php?cid=1234">
            Supporting Charities In Toronto, ON</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of putting the content back, have you tried bringing the menu forward? `z-index: 100` on the menus may fix it.

Comment: Yes, did try that and it didn't work. When you make something fixed, it takes out of the flow of the code so z-index won't have effect on it.

Comment: Um, that's wrong. `z-index` applies to any element that isn't `static`...

Comment: Thanks everyone. It looks like everyone was right. I had tried almost every  combination but after removing z-index from divs and applying to sticky menus, that did the trick. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the z-index property from the salebox div element.

Instead you can try to apply the z-index property to the fixed menu bar, that is greater than the elements inside the body element.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately anchor doesn't work with z-index negative.

increase all the z-index of your element in the page to make the z-index of your class salebox become positive but still lower as the other element of your page.

```
.salebox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: auto 10px 20px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

To make sure that your element have a greater z-index than the other elements you can do :

```
html, body {
 z-index : 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks but relative or absolute position items are still overlapping the menu as I scroll

Comment: have you try to make the z-index of all the other element greater than yours ? i add a new element in the reply it can maybe solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your z-index a positive number.

If it scrolls above the fixed menus, you'll need to make sure those menus have a higher z-index than the .salebox z-index.